# Lambda Low Latency Messaging Options

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a Lambda that requires messages to be sent to another Lambda to perform some action.  In my particular case it is passing a message to a Lambda in order for it to perform HTTP requests and refresh cache entries.

Currently I am relying on the AWS SDK to send an SQS message.  The mechanics of this are working fine.  The concern that I have is that the SQS send method call takes around 50ms on average to complete.  Considering I'm in a Lambda, I am unable to perform this in the background and expect for it to complete before the Lambda returns and is frozen.

This is further compounded if I need to make multiple SQS send calls, which is particularly bad as the Lambda is responsible for responding to low-latency HTTP requests.

Are there any alternatives in AWS for communicating between Lambdas that does not require a synchronous API call, and that exhibits more of a fire and forget and asynchronous behavior?

Comment: [EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) supports lambda in asynchronius mode. Maybe worth looking into this?

Comment: The core issue seems to be that regardless of underlying technology (SQS, SNS, EventBridge), they all rely on HTTP API calls to the AWS APIs, which introduces some form of latency that's likely very similar.  Unless perhaps the SQS call waits for some action to be completed, and EventBridge does not and returns an immediate 202.  That's the part that's not clear to me in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Though there are several approaches to trigger one lambda from another, (in my experience) one of the fastest methods would be to directly trigger the ultimate lambda's ARN.

Did you try invoking one Lambda from the other using AWS SDKs?
(for e.g. in Python using Boto3, I achieved it like this).

See below, the parameter `InvocationType = 'Event'` helps in invoking target Lambda asynchronously.

Below code takes 2 parameters (`name`, which can be either your target Lambda function's name or its ARN, `params` is a JSON object with input parameters you would want to pass as input). Try it out!

```py
import boto3, json


def invoke_lambda(name, params):

    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

    params_bytes = json.dumps(params).encode()
    try:
        response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName = name,
                                        InvocationType = 'Event',
                                        LogType = 'Tail',
                                        Payload = params_bytes)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
        return None

    return response
```

Hope it helps!

For more, refer to [Lambda's Invoke Event](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html) on Boto3 docs.

Alternatively, you can use [Lambda's Async Invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke_async) as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give exact answers without knowing what language are you writing the Lambda function in. To at least make "warm" function invocations faster I would make sure you are creating the SQS client outside of the Lambda event handler so it can reuse the connection. The AWS SDK should use an HTTP connection pool so it doesn't have to re-establish a connection and go through the SSL handshake and all that every time you make an SQS request, as long as you reuse the SQS client.

If that's still not fast enough, I would have the Lambda function handling the HTTP request pass off the "background" work to another Lambda function, via an asynchronous call. Then the first Lambda function can return an HTTP response, while the second Lambda function continues to do work.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using Go, and currently do have the HTTP client and pool outside the handler.    The latency of the send matches what this article mentions as well, so I believe it's accurate - https://softwaremill.com/amazon-sqs-performance-latency/.  I may have to go the async/event invocation route.  You lose out on some of the benefits of a queue, but in my use-case it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try to use Lambda Destinations depending on you use case. With this you don't need to put things in a queue manually.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/

But it limits your flexibility. From my point of view chaining lambdas directly is an antipattern and if you would need that, go for step functions